# Select query returning invalid results with datetime field

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a `DateTime` field named `dt_cadastro` with this content `15/04/2013 11:14:59`, then I do this query

```
SELECT descricao, dt_cadastro
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE dt_cadastro   >= '11/05/2013 00:00:00' AND dt_cadastro <= '11/05/2013 23:59:59';
```

And it DOES return me this row. Why ? If I specified the `DateTime` value bigger than the date that is on my table... Anyone could explain it to me please? I'm trying to make a query to return me all rows on an interval of dates like, `Where dt_cadastro >= @date1 AND dt_cadastro <= @date2`. But it still returning me rows when it should return me `EmptySet`. I'm using C# - Asp.net.
Also I tried using `Between` but when using `between` it NEVER returns me any value...
`Sample`

```
 string sql = "SELECT proj.descricao AS projeto, func.descricao AS funcionalidade, clb.clube AS cliente, ch.descricao
              FROM MyTable ch 
                   INNER JOIN projetos proj ON ch.projeto = proj.id 
                   INNER JOIN funcionalidades func ON ch.funcionalidade = func.id 
                   INNER JOIN clubes clb ON ch.clube = clb.id
              WHERE ch.dt_cadastro >= @dt_inicial AND ch.dt_cadastro <= @dt_final";

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.CommandText = sql;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_inicial", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = rel.Dt_Inicial;  
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_final", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = rel.Dt_Final;
```

Comment: Are you very sure it's a `DATETIME` column and not a `VARCHAR` one? I have never seen `DATETIME` columns formatted the way you seem to have..

Comment: @Wrikken Yes, I'm sure, if you want I may post a picture... I'm getting crazy, I just don't know what to do... I just deleted my column and created it again, but still the same...

Comment: MySQL stores date in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. I am wondering how you are able to store it in "15/04/2013 11:14:59" format.

Comment: @Vishy When I was making the `insert` of this row, I did like so:  
`INSERT INTO MyTable (field1, field2, dt_cadastro) VALUES (value1, value2, NOW());` May be it's what is making the problem ?

Comment: I executed `insert into test(dt) values(NOW())` and I see `2013-04-16 00:47:12` in the table.

Comment: Where I'm from, the date format is `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` ;s I don't know what to tell you. I never get problem with this before... I just don't know what to do ;s getting crazy ! I'm using `AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender` I don't know if it minds ?

Comment: mysql doesn't care where you're from, the format is fixed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: @Sebas I see... I'm sure it is a `DateTime` field and NOT a varchar. Now I'm lost without knowing what to do u.u ohmygosh

Comment: @Ghaleon, please post a sample of `SELECT dt_cadastro FROM mytable`, directly from mysql

Comment: @Sebas Updated my question, is that a `sample` ? I'm not sure ;x

Comment: no, i was asking for an extract of your database datas. But now you confused me I don't know how you run queries.

Comment: @Sebas Sorry for my dumbish Sebas, but I don't know where I get that, is the DDL of my table? ;s -Updated my question-

Comment: just run the darn query :D

Comment: @Sebas I restarted the `MySql` and my sql manager... But still the same, and when I use `between` it `NEVER` returns me any value... **UPDATE** I guess I Solved the problem, i did this:  `WHERE responsavel = 1 AND dt_cadastro BETWEEN ('2013/04/15 16:05:00') AND ('2013/04/20');` WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem... I just had to Restart my `MySql` and reopen my `Sql Manager`... I don't know why or what was causing these troubles, but after I restart both, it worked fine !